# find max among 3 (user populated) arrays (which may be empty)

Tags: arrays, swift

I am populating 3 arrays and I've no idea which one is being populated (depends on user). My goal is 2 fold.

1. find which array is being populated
2. find the Max value Among the 3 arrays (or the arrays which are populated)

eg:

```
hrGenY    = [100,101,102]
cadGenY   = [80,  81, 82]
powerGenY = [100,104,106]
```

This is what I'm doing right now. (This code here is just to determine which array is being populated and NOT nil)

```
var whichTelemery: [Int] = []
if !powerGenY.isEmpty {
  whichTelemery = powerGenY
} else if !hrGenY.isEmpty {
  whichTelemery = hrGenY
} else if !cadGenY.isEmpty {
  whichTelemery = cadGenY
}
```

after which I utilise this to determine the X & Y scale for my chart. I use whichever is the Max to normalise the scale.

```
      var yMax: CGFloat = 0.0
      var xMax: CGFloat = 0.0
      
      var yMaxTemp: [CGFloat] = [0,0]
      var xMaxTemp: [CGFloat] = [0,0]
  
   // Determine yMax & xMax for Scale Resolution
   if !dataPointsY.isEmpty {
      xMaxTemp[0] = dataPointsX.max()!
      yMaxTemp[0] = CGFloat((dataPointsY.max()! >= ftpPlus) ? (1.2*dataPointsY.max()!) : ftpPlus)
      
      xMax = xMaxTemp.max()!
      yMax = yMaxTemp.max()!
    }
    
    if !whichTelemery.isEmpty && dataPointsY.isEmpty {
      xMaxTemp[1] = CGFloat(whichTelemery.count < 900 ? 900 : whichTelemery.count + 1)
      yMaxTemp[1] = CGFloat((CGFloat(whichTelemery.max()!) >= ftpPlus) ? (1.2*CGFloat(whichTelemery.max()!)) : ftpPlus)
      
      xMax = xMaxTemp.max()!
      yMax = yMaxTemp.max()!
    }
```

The problem with this method is I am making the assumption that the user's power (if populated) will always be higher than the HR(heart rate) which may not be true. When this happens, the HR line will not get drawn as it's above the yMax limit.

The way I'm thinking of doing it is very crude which would involve yet another group of checks to see which of the 3 arrays has the highest number. Would appreciate some better more elegant way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about getting the max value for your normalisation by doing

```
let max = [hrGenY.max() ?? 0.0, cadGenY.max() ?? 0.0, powerGenY.max() ?? 0.0].max()
```

Comment: After posting the question, I came up with     ```whichTelemeryMax[0] = powerGenY.max() ?? 0```   ```whichTelemeryMax[1] = hrGenY.max() ?? 0```   ```whichTelemeryMax[2] = cadGenY.max() ?? 0``` which is similar like yours but yours if better as 1 line

Comment: @myjunk `[hrGenY, cadGenY, powerGenY].compactMap { $0.max() }.max() ?? .zero`